# Enyim (Memcached C# client) returning "Socket bound to localhost:11211 has N unread data" warn

Tags: c#, memcached

I am using Enyim to communicate with the Memcached server.
First time I start my application it is running smoothly with the Enyim client. If I stop and start again my application I receive Enyim warning "Socket bound to localhost:11211 has 1160 unread data! This is probably a bug in the code. InstanceID was 06edb637-cff3-438d-8a02-ae1e1f622d72." and all unread bytes are displayed.

I analyzed Enyim source code and this is part that returns warning:

```
// discard any buffered data
this.inputStream.Flush();

int available = this.socket.Available;

if (available > 0)
{
 if (log.IsWarnEnabled)
 log.WarnFormat("Socket bound to {0} has {1} unread data! This is probably a bug in the code. InstanceID was {2}.", this.socket.RemoteEndPoint, available, this.InstanceId);
....
....
```

My guess is that memcached has some unanswered silent gets issued by the Enyim from last application invocation.

Did anyone else had similar problems?
Am I doing something wrong or is this some known issue?

Thank You.

Comment: Are you calling dispose, or utilizing a using block to release the client?